# Adding a key to an empty hstore column

Tags: postgresql

According to the postgres documentation, you add a key to an hstore column as follows:

```
UPDATE tab SET h = h || ('c' => '3');
```

But it seems to only work if the hstore field is not empty. For example:

```
postgres=# create table htest (t text, h hstore);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into htest (t) VALUES ('key');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# update htest set h = h || ('foo'=>'bar') where t='key';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from htest;
  t  | h 
-----+---
 key | 
(1 row)
```

The update was successful, yet the hstore was not updated. However:

```
postgres=# update htest set h = ('foo'=>'bar') where t='key';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from htest;
  t  |      h       
-----+--------------
 key | "foo"=>"bar"
(1 row)

postgres=# update htest set h = h || ('bar'=>'foo') where t='key';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from htest;
  t  |             h              
-----+----------------------------
 key | "bar"=>"foo", "foo"=>"bar"
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to atomically add a key to an hstore without first checking if the hstore is empty?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the hstore you have is null, and null OR some hstore is null.

The best solution I have, which is probably not the best solution, is to make the table with a default empty hstore rather than allowing null. Then your examples work as you would like:

```
postgres=# create table htest (t text, h hstore default hstore(array[]::varchar[]));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into htest (t) values ('key');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# update htest set h = h || ('foo'=>'bar') where t='key';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from htest;
  t  |      h       
-----+--------------
 key | "foo"=>"bar"
(1 row)
```

I unfortunately do not see a cleaner way to create an empty hstore than `hstore(array[]::varchar[])` but that doesn't mean there isn't a better way. You could incorporate this into your hstore update from before like so:

```
update htest set h = coalesce(h, hstore(array[]::varchar[])) || ('foo'=>'bar') where t='key';
```

This way you don't need to recreate the table. I find that fairly gross though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that my hstore was null, but I wasn't aware that that was any different from an empty hstore.

Comment: Might be a helpful note to someone in the future.  I'm using 8.4 and I create the empty hstore with hstore('') instead of hstore(array[]::varchar[])

Answer (score 7):

To avoid this you need to ensure the hstore is created as empty and not null. You can add an empty hstore to an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE htest ADD h HSTORE NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Or you can alter your existing hstore to empty:

```
ALTER TABLE htest ALTER COLUMN h SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE htest ALTER COLUMN h SET DEFAULT '';
```

Please note that exiting values cannot be null when you set the column to 'NOT NULL'.

Answer (score 6):

how about:

```
UPDATE htest SET h = COALESCE(h, '') || ('foo'=>'bar') WHERE t='key';
```

Answer (score 5):

For Postgres version **> 9.1**:

```
UPDATE htest SET h = COALESCE(h, hstore('')) || hstore('foo', 'bar') WHERE t='key';
```