# Set default hstore column key value pairs via migration or psql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, psql, hstore

I have an `hstore` column in my `users` table and seem to be unable to set the default key value pairs via migration or psql.

I have referred to this question [Adding a key to an empty hstore column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317971/adding-a-key-to-an-empty-hstore-column), but with no success.

And as far as a migration solution referred to this article, http://www.economyofeffort.com/2014/12/16/postgres-hstore-default-value-in-rails-4/

But was unable to get by the `nil` issue.

How can I create a migration that adds key, value pair defaults to an `hstore` column in a table? example... `value1 = '1', value2 = '2'`?

Also, how might I do this via `psql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently few people have had this problem, I figured out the `psql` solution after a lot of trial and error and it was insanely simple.

```
UPDATE users SET settings = '"value1"=>"1", "value2"=>"2"';
```

Still interested in migration solution however.

Comment: This doesn't `add a settings column`. It just updates values in an existing column `settings` in all rows. Your answer doesn't seem to match your question.

Comment: Have you tried using `execute`? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#when-helpers-aren-t-enough

Answer (score 2):

In `Rails 4` you just set the ruby hash with the default values for the hstore

```
class AddStatisticsToOffers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :offers, :statistics, :hstore, default: {total_visitors: 0}, null: false
  end
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  hstore_accessor :statistics,
              total_visitors:     :integer
end

class OffersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { @offer.total_visitors += 1; @offer.save }
    end
  end
end
```